# Функция, которая вычитает элементы массива

Tags: php

Есть функция, которая складывает элементы массива array_sum.

А я хочу сделать, которая, вычитает элементы массива и у меня не получается.

```
$arr2 = array(1,2,3,4);


function foo2($mass, $znak){
    $res = $mass[0];
    foreach($mass as $value){
        echo $res = $res - $value;
    };

    return $res;
};

foo2($arr2);
```

если в переменную $res записать 0, то сразу будет из нуля вычитаться 1,
а мне нужно, что бы сначала, из 1 вычиталось 2.

Как это сделать?

Должно получиться 1-2-3-4 = -8

И как сделать, что бы в функцию, можно было передавать параметр, который решает, что сделать с элементами? минус, плюс

Answer (score 2):

```
function foo2($mass, $znak){

    $sum = 0;
    foreach($mass as $value){
        $sum = $sum + $value;
    }

    if($znak == '+') return $sum;
    else return $mass[0] - ($sum - $mass[0]);

}
```

У меня работает.

Comment: не работает, вообще ничего не выводит

Comment: Работает, забыл добавить echo

Answer (score 1):

Прибавьте к результату первый элемент еще раз

```
$arr2 = array(1,2,3,4);

function foo2($mass){
    $res = $mass[0];
    foreach($mass as $value){
        $res = $res - $value;
    };

    // 1 - 1 + 1 = 1
    return $res + $mass[0];
};

echo foo2($arr2);
```

Другой вариант. Тут можно передать функцию которую надо применить к массиву.

```
$arr2 = array(1,2,3,4);

function sum($carry, $item)
{
    $carry += $item;
    return $carry;
}

function sub($carry, $item)
{
    $carry -= $item;
    return $carry;
}

// работает только с sub или sum
function foo2($mass, $func){
    $res = array_reduce($mass, $func, $mass[0]);

    return call_user_func($func, $res, -$mass[0]);
}

echo foo2($arr2, "sub");
echo "\n";
echo foo2($arr2, "sum");
```

Comment: и ничего не изменилось

Comment: а не, изменилось

Comment: я исправил ответ. теперь все должно работать верно. проверить можно тут http://ideone.com/VHSO24

Comment: ошибку выдаёт Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_OBJECT_OPERATOR in C:\OpenServer\domains\localhost\php\loft\dz2.php on line 145

Comment: 145 строка   return (new MyMath($arr)) -> $methname();

Comment: @DivMan у меня в примере нет, ни 145 строки, ни MyMath. Так что это я не знаю причины этой ошибки.

Answer (score 1):

```
class MyMath{

private $arr;

public function __construct($arr){
  $this -> arr = $arr;
}

public function sum()
  $res = 0;
  foreach($this -> arr as $item => $val){
    $res += $val;
  }
  return $res;
}

public function subtraction(){
  $res = 0;
  foreach($this -> arr as $item => $val){
    $res = $item ? $res - $val : $val;
  }
}

}

function callMyMath($arr, $methname){
  return (new MyMath($arr)) -> $methname();
}

// 'sum' or 'subtraction'
callMyMath([3,5,6,7], 'sum');
```

Ну вдруг если понадобиться удобно расширяемый класс, то вот)